# CSS transform: rotate top-left corner of child over bottom-left corner of parent

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Is there a way how to automatically achieve this without the knowledge of line height/parent height with negative `translate`?

Ideal solutions:

- `transform: translate(-100% of parent height or 1 line height here pls)`
- `transform-origin: top left over bottom left`

desired: [image] actual result: [image]

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimareq/crtx509e/)

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-left-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-90deg)/*translate(-20px)*/;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    CONCEPT
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-left-color: red;
  margin-top:100px;
  position:absolute;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    CONCEPT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG Genius! This will also work with any parent height for child with `position:absolute; bottom: 0px`.

Comment: @Qwerty yes ;) it will also work for any child height/width .. well it will always work ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems like the magic for me was in absolute position of the child. This way the parent shrinks to zero height where top-left corner becomes equal to bottom-left corner.

[image]

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
}
```

This solution won't work however for parents that won't shrink due to other content.